# Which header file of system call numbers is correct?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls

I'm recently doing some kernel coding and I found 2 *`unistd.h`* files.

The location of the first one is *`/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`*. The second one is from the source code of the kernel: *`linux/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`*.
The source code's version is the same with my kernel's, but the two header files 
differ from each other.

*`/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`* (from my PC):

```
#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
#define __NR_stat 4
#define __NR_fstat 5
#define __NR_lstat 6
#define __NR_poll 7
#define __NR_lseek 8
#define __NR_mmap 9
```

*`linux/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`* (from the source):

```
#define __NR_io_setup 0
__SC_COMP(__NR_io_setup, sys_io_setup, compat_sys_io_setup)
#define __NR_io_destroy 1
__SYSCALL(__NR_io_destroy, sys_io_destroy)
#define __NR_io_submit 2
__SC_COMP(__NR_io_submit, sys_io_submit, compat_sys_io_submit)
#define __NR_io_cancel 3
__SYSCALL(__NR_io_cancel, sys_io_cancel)
#define __NR_io_getevents 4
__SC_COMP(__NR_io_getevents, sys_io_getevents, compat_sys_io_getevents)

/* fs/xattr.c */
#define __NR_setxattr 5
__SYSCALL(__NR_setxattr, sys_setxattr)
#define __NR_lsetxattr 6
__SYSCALL(__NR_lsetxattr, sys_lsetxattr)
#define __NR_fsetxattr 7
__SYSCALL(__NR_fsetxattr, sys_fsetxattr)
#define __NR_getxattr 8
__SYSCALL(__NR_getxattr, sys_getxattr)
#define __NR_lgetxattr 9
```

What's the difference? Which one should I use to indexing the `sys_call_table`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asm-generic` one is a template version that can be used if you're developing a new architecture for the kernel. I believe you'll find that there are actually many versions of `unistd.h` in the kernel source, because the ordering of system calls (and indeed system call existence) varies by architecture. Try this from the root of your kernel source hierarchy:

```
find . -name 'unistd*.h'
```

For x86 specifically, the `uapi` version is *generated* when you build the kernel. See the `Makefile` and various `*.tbl` files in `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/` directory. This ends up generating files:

```
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
```

(all of which are `#include`d from a stub `unistd.h` file).

Ultimately the creation of a linux "distro" is very architecture-specific, so it's up to the distro creator to copy the correct `unistd.h` file(s) into some appropriate location within the `/usr/include` hierarchy. (And of course, your `libc` will also need to be compiled against the correct version in order for ordinary `libc` system calls to work correctly.)

In summary, the version in `/usr/include/asm` had *better* match your running kernel or it won't be possible to correctly generate an ad-hoc system call from a user process on your system, but you *shouldn't* be using that one within the kernel source hierarchy, because categorically the kernel source hierarchy never relies on user space headers. Within the kernel source, the mechanism for indexing that table is architecture-dependent because the layout and ordering of the table is itself architecture-dependent, and only architecture-specific code (the system call entry code) normally accesses the table, so only that code "needs to know" the correct indices.

Now if you're creating a new system call, you would need to go define its number in all of the `unistd.h` files for all of the architectures you want it to appear in.

Comment: */usr/include/asm had better match your running kernel* The system-call ABI is extremely stable; they don't recycle old numbers or swap them around between kernel versions.  New versions of system calls with args passed differently get a new name, like `mmap2` for Linux's 32-bit x86 `int 0x80` ABI, and `umount2`, or `renameat2` among others also present on x86-64.   (Many of the `...2` syscalls are actually documented as separate system calls in the man page, taking an extra `flags` arg)

Comment: But yeah, if you're creating multiple new system calls in different forks of the source, then the right call numbers could be an issue when rebuilding binaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is really dependent on the architecture you're looking for. This changes from arch to arch and is usually placed somewhere under the `arch/$ARCH` folder. For embedded architectures this is usually a hardcoded table that might even change for different variants.

For x86/64 this table is auto generated in build time as you can see in arch/x86/Makefile

```
syscall32 := $(srctree)/$(src)/syscall_32.tbl
syscall64 := $(srctree)/$(src)/syscall_64.tbl
...
$(uapi)/unistd_32.h: $(syscall32) $(syshdr)
    $(call if_changed,syshdr)
...
$(uapi)/unistd_64.h: $(syscall64) $(syshdr)
    $(call if_changed,syshdr)
```

Which basically calls the `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscallhdr.sh` script that will automatically generate your `unistd_32.h`/`unistd_x32.h`/`unistd_64.h` files according to your `menuconfig`.

This means that if you're looking for that actual syscall tables for x86/x64 they are found here:
`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`/`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`